# Row selection for QLIK Sense table

Tags: qliksense

I have trouble ticket data, with a status field (either Open or Closed).

I'd like to make a sheet that shows graphs (and a table) for data associated with "open" rows - and I don't want a filter to do the subsetting.  Graphs on this sheet only make sense for "Open" tickets.

I can do bar charts (I think) with set selection logic.
But I'd also like a table of open tickets, sorted by age.

How can I specify that my table only have rows where status == "Open"?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a calculated dimension.

While editing, create a new Dimension under master items. Then, add an expression like:

If([Status]='Open',[TicketId])

and using it in a table would give you a table with the TicketIds corresponding to Open tickets.

Reference information can be found on the Qlik Sense help site:

http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/2.2/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Dimensions/calculated-dimensions.htm

http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/2.2/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Dimensions/create-calculated-dimension.htm

Please read the notes on performance, and see whether this solution suits your application.